# define для нескольких слов

Tags: c++

Можно ли с помощью директивы `#define` заменить не одно слово на другое, а сразу кусок текста на другой кусок?

Например, заменить всякое вхождение `int foo()` в файле на `void bar()`.

Comment: Нет. Меняется только одно слово (но может быть заменено несколькими, в  т.ч. среди них могут быть левые части других `#define`)

Comment: @avp а как эти вложенные дефайны будут работать? В каком порядке относительно верхних?

Comment: Это вы все боритесь с той проблемой XY? Советы менять дефайнами куски кода чтобы оно не ломалось при линковке из ответа к предыдущему вопросу достаточно бестолковый.

Comment: @VTT не, прошлые вопросы я решил. Достаточно было .cpp файл включить, ведь там есть и объявление и определение шаблонного класса (я дал ответ). Сейчас борюсь с другими проблемами в этом же проекте

Comment: @Андрей, обычно порядок не важен, но вообще-то почитайте о [подстановках в препроцессоре](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/cpp/Object-like-Macros.html#Object-like-Macros)